# How to use media queries correctly to reduce font size?

Tags: fonts, size, media, reduce

I'm trying to set my CSS so that font sizes decease when viewed on mobile devices. I've spent all day trying to figure this out, but am now stumped.

I found media query code that I think should solve the issue, however it's not happening for me, font size remains standard size when viewing on mobile (Galaxy Nexus).

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
body {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
    html { font-size: 70%; }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    html { font-size: 80%; }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    html { font-size: 120%; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    html { font-size: 200%; }
}
```

Spot any errors please? Could there be something else within my CSS blocking this from working correctly?

Here's what it looks like in ebays app... (sorry can't embed images yet as don't have 10 rep)...

[Text waaay to big on mobile](http://i87.photobucket.com/albums/k135/dupfold31/080120154225_zpsa2cf5b32.jpg)

**[UPDATE]**
Part fixed now where the main body of text does now resize, however, as seen in this picture...

[Click to view pic](http://i87.photobucket.com/albums/k135/dupfold31/080120154227_zpsbbf482fb.jpg)

...any text within a table does not resize. Should the existing media query resize this text also, or do I need to add a table tag? If so can someone provide code example please as I've tried by failed. I simply want table text to be reduced in size along with the main body text.

Thank you

**[UPDATE]**
Table as per request...

```
<table style="margin-bottom:15px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:0px">
   <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:text-top; padding:3px">Platform:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align:text-top">Xbox.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:text-top; padding:3px">Game Condition:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align:text-top">Used game - Good.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:text-top; padding:3px">Includes:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align:text-top">Disc, manual, case &amp; cover.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:text-top; padding:3px">Region:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align:text-top">PAL.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:text-top; padding:3px">Players:</th>
              <td style="vertical-align:text-top">1-2.</td>
            </tr>
              <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:text-top; padding:3px">Xbox 360 Compatible:</th>
              <td><strong>NO - NOT</strong> compatible.</td>
            </tr>
  </table>
```

**[UPDATE]**
All hail sodawillow, thank you! :) The below worked, although not sure if code is exactly as should be? I set table font at 62.5% at first, but this resulted in the text being too small, so set to 100% and looks good now.

Looks fine on my mobile, but that's just one screen size, so do you see any corrections needed please? Any adverse effects from table font being 100%? Should table font also be added to @media queries?

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
table { font-size: 100% }
body {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
    html { font-size: 70%; }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    html { font-size: 80%; }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    html { font-size: 100%; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    html { font-size: 120%; }
}
```

Comment: Your link points to eBay. Your code is working, at least on a desktop. I don't have a mobile to try, sorry.

Comment: Hi sodawillow. That's correct, as it needs to be view on ebay app, or m.ebay via mobile. There code is not working as can be seen in the image example link above "Text waaay to big on mobile'.

Comment: Hey! Just checked via ebay app again and now paragraph text size has reduced! Only issue remaining is the text within tables still remain too big. Is there a way to include tables within the media query please?

Comment: Yes you can, add `table` tags in the media queries where you want to change the table attributes

Comment: Thank you, but could you give a code example please, as I've already tried doing this but had no such luck, so clearly my code is wrong. I've updated original post to show exactly what is happening.

Comment: (you shouldn't mix inline styles and stylesheets, for clarity) --- If you add `table` in your media queries, with the desired `font-size`, does it work ? If no, try with `table *` as selector ?

Comment: Believe me I tried not to mix styles, but due ecommerce platform/templates I use to list on ebay, and lack of time and knowledge I had no other choose for now. Update above :)

Comment: I don't see *any* change in your CSS. Read my comments, update and test your CSS

Comment: Update is there, think I was still adding it as you replied. I said 'update above' before update was above. I do make things difficult! :)

Comment: Put `table` tags **inside** the media queries if you want the tables to change too :)

Comment: Many thanks for your help sodawillow, it's much appreciated as this was driving me nuts! All sort now thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an *example* of what you can do with media queries, but it may not be what you want since I still have to understand that :).

The style choices I made are mostly ugly, I only wanted to show the basic workings of media queries ; maybe you'll be able to explain what you need then.

Open in full page and resize the window horizontally.

```css
body {
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid pink;
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    font-size: 2em; 
  }

  table {
    border: 4px solid blue;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.5em; 
  }

  table {
    border: 8px solid green;
    width: 85%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1em; 
  }

  table {
    border: 16px solid red;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>(open me in full page) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum molestias eius veniam enim eos! Debitis commodi, in, aliquam asperiores molestias, magnam ipsam animi beatae, tenetur similique et mollitia necessitatibus. Nesciunt?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanks sodawillow, this is very helpful, but still not able to fix the issue I have. The best way to understand the issue is to view the second image in my original post. In that image you'll see a table and main body of text on mobile. The main body is resizing as expected, but the text within the table is not, and remains at it's default large 'desktop' size. I simply need to have all text within table reduced so as it's not so massive when viewing on a mobile.

Comment: Please post the HTML code for the table (I guess we're now taking about the part between "Platform" and "compatible") in your question

Comment: Yes that's correct, none of the text within tables are being reduced in size for some reason. Code added above. Strangely when testing in jsfiddle, table text does reduce in size, but as seen from picture, not so within my ebay listing.