# Div centered on desktop, not on mobile device

Tags: html, css

When centering a div within another, I succeed on desktop, I try in chrome's built in 'inspect' resolution change, but on 'mobile' the div stays at the bottom of the other div. Can anybody help, and see why the div is centered in the 'desktop mode', but not in the 'mobile mode'? Thank you

```css
.headercontainer {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.header-title {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 2em;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -40%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.header-title h1 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #d1d1d1;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-image {
    background-image: url("images/Westminster.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5em;
    height:60vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    z-index: -3;
}
```

```html
<div class = "headercontainer">
  <div class = "header-image">
    <div class = "header-title">
      <h1> Anarchists and Autocrats </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use flex for centering.

Comment: You may want to set `height: 100%` both for `head`, `body` and `.headercontainer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `position:absolute` instead of using `position:fixed`.
Go through my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcs3uygf/65/) Link or try below written code:

HTML Code -

```
<div class="headercontainer">
    <div class="header-image">
        <div class="header-title">
            <h1> Anarchists and Autocrats </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code -

```
.headercontainer {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.header-title {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    font-size: 2em;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.header-title h1 {
    color: #404040;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #d1d1d1;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-image {
    background: url("https://www.nyhabitat.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/westminster-london-houses-parliament-big-ben-thames-river.jpg") center/ cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5em;
    height: 60vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -3;
}
```

Comment: instead of giving him code, it'd be more informative for future users to explain what was wrong with the original code as well

Comment: I have updated my code. @pandavenger. Also I provide solution so that user can see it running live.

Comment: Hello. This works, but I really do need the text to not move, and be fixed. Is there any way to do this, or is this impossible?

Comment: Try to maintain `font-size` of your text according to screen size using `media` query in CSS. @SimplySnap

Comment: Do you know how I'd do this? Sorry to be a bother

Comment: Read about how to use `media` queries in CSS and make your text `font-size` according to device size. @SimplySnap

Comment: I really hate to be annoying, but using the @media query, would I increase the font size to keep it centered, in fixed position? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, you can increase or decrease of `font-size` by using `media query`. @SimplySnap You can also see a live example like this [example1](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_responsive_text2) and [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842735/how-to-use-media-queries-correctly-to-reduce-font-size).

Comment: Thank you so much! And would you recommend that I decrease font size as the window gets smaller?

Comment: If text goes outside from screen in small devices then you should decrease it to maintain in screen otherwise you can leave it. @SimplySnap